# FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser does not create user

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've already found the answer to this problem, I am posting this here since I was unable to find the answer on here.

The problem is that `FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser` does not throw an error, but the user is also not created. Which shouldn't even be possible since the Firebase docs say if there is no error in the completion handler then the account creation was successful.

The documentation states that any password validation needs to be done by the app before calling `FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser`, but doesn't say that there are any requirements set by Firebase.

So by all sources of available information, if the completion handler doesn't pass an error, the account must be there, but it is possible to get no error and also not have the account created.

Answer (score 3):

When creating a user, be sure to handle errors.

For example:

```
app.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword("tooshort@firebaseui.com", "fire")
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Shows the follow error in the JavaScript console:

```
{code: "auth/weak-password", message: "Password should be at least 6 characters"}
```

In swift you can get the same output by implementing a completion block. See the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_auth#aeaee7fcef878990954f8e72f7278cd7d), which also contains the error code you'll be getting `FIRAuthErrorCodeWeakPassword`.

Comment: I did implement a completion handler, and was not getting an error passed into that. When I mentioned this to google, they pointed me there too, but I never got an error. But you make a good point for future coders that they should be implementing error catching/handling.

Comment: If you implemented a completion handler and it didn't show this error, I'd consider that a bug. Can you share the ]minimal, complete code that reproduces this behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is incomplete. If you attempt to create an account with a password less than 6 characters it fails.

If you try to create the account in the online console for your Firebase app, it will fail and give you an error message stating such. But if you try to do it from within the app, it can silently fail. The documentation says an error can be thrown for this issue, but it apparently won't always happen since I never got that error.

So to avoid this, check your password strings since they need to be at least 6 characters for it to succeed on Google's end.